# How to INNER JOIN more than two categories?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join, categories

I'm a little confused in here and need some help...

the situation is I've made three tables(fr_Leagues, fr_nations and fr_confeds), all i want to do is add a league which shows the name of the categories not the i.d with pagination. Here is the code:

NOW FIXED!

```
  "SELECT 
 a.id as confed_id,
 a.fr_short_name as confed_name, 
     b.id as nation_id,
 b.fr_name as nation_name,
 c.id as league_id,
 c.fr_name as league_name"
." FROM fr_confeds as a 
INNER JOIN fr_nations as b ON a.id = b.confed_id 
INNER JOIN fr_leagues as c ON b.id = c.nation_id"
." LIMIT $paginate->start, $paginate->limit"
```

Comment: can you post the schema of your tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing on how to link the different tables together. On each INNER JOIN, you need to have it:

```
INNER JOIN fr_nations ON a.<someColumn> = b.<anotherColumn> INNER JOIN fr_leagues ON a.<someColumn> = b.<anotherColumn>
```

Comment: can you please be more specific?

Comment: getting this error:
#1054 - Unknown column 'C.league_id' in 'on clause'

this is what i added:
FROM fr_confeds as A INNER JOIN fr_nations as B ON A.id = B.confed_id INNER JOIN fr_leagues as C ON B.confed_id = C.league_id LIMIT $paginate->start, $paginate->limit

Comment: @HiroHito: I only made the SQL more visible, it's what Johann originally posted by he didn't use the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

*USE THIS QUERY*

SELECT * FROM fr_confeds as A

INNER JOIN fr_nations as B ON A.id = B.confed_id

INNER JOIN fr_leagues as C ON B.confed_id = C.league_id

LIMIT $paginate->start, $paginate->limit

Comment: it shows this error:
#1054 - Unknown column 'C.league_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: if league_id is not a primary key means........that is not possible to make inner join...give me the three tables structures..

Comment: I've got this fixed, can you take a look at my other question. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052196/mysql-error-1054-unknown-column-on-clause